# Problems using MaterializeCSS in a Lightning Component on Community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, aura, locker-service, community-builder

I was originally able to use Materialize in my components by adding the below three lines in the "head" markup in the advanced settings of each page. (very easy)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Now with lightning locker service enabled, i am forbidden to use the script tag in the head markup.

I have tried uploading the .js and .css files as static resources and referencing them using the  but for some reason the libraries do not load. (I have an "`afterScriptsLoaded`" function which never gets called.)

However, i do not see any error messages in the inspector.
I do get one error but only when i access the page via the community builder,

> cannot assign to read only property 'requestAnimationFrame'

Please help!

Comment: Please provide a gitgist of your code or the markup you are using to load the scripts. Also these things to keep in mind:
1. Use ltng:require to load the static resources(You probably are doing that since you referred to *afterScriptsLoaded*)
2. The javascript libraries that you are loading have to be [strict mode][1] compliant. 

Also, if you haven't already, please get in touch with salesforce support and create a case to help you track this issue.
  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode